# Efficiently put sorted ArrayList in sorted data structure and find amount of numbers smaller than x, using Java

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, tree

I have an array list which is already sorted. I wish to put it in a sorted data structure such that I can easily find the number of items smaller than a specified number.

This is how I was doing it so far:

```
TreeSet<Integer> sortedList = new TreeSet<>(myArrayList); // This is slow
```

And if I wanted to find the amount of numbers smaller than or equal to 50 (for example) then I would do it like so:

```
sortedList.headSet(50, true).size(); // This is not that slow
```

All of this looks very inefficient. This is mainly because of the fact that `myArrayList` is already sorted and initializing a TreeSet is very slow.

Please note that the array list is very large and the number of queries is quite small (about 10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `myArrayList` is already sorted and contains no duplicates, the binary search is your friend. Use `Collections.binarySearch`. The `binarySearch` returns either the index of existing element (so you have `idx+1` elements less or equal) or the *insertion point* where the given element should be inserted (so `-idx-1` is the number of elements which are strictly less, no equal element).

```
public static int countLessOrEqual(List<Integer> nums, int limit) {
    int idx = Collections.binarySearch(nums, limit);
    if(idx < 0) return -idx-1;
    return idx+1;
}
```

Usage example:

```
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1, 10, 23, 31, 50, 65, 71, 89, 100);
System.out.println(countLessOrEqual(nums, 50)); // 5
System.out.println(countLessOrEqual(nums, 51)); // 5
System.out.println(countLessOrEqual(nums, 49)); // 4
System.out.println(countLessOrEqual(nums, 0));  // 0
System.out.println(countLessOrEqual(nums, 300)); // 9
```

If your input list is sorted, but contains duplicates, all duplicates are adjacent, so you can preprocess the list once and remove them (much faster than building a `TreeSet`):

```
public static List<Integer> removeAdjacentDuplicates(List<Integer> input) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer last = null;
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); i++) {
        Integer cur = input.get(i);
        if(i == 0 || !cur.equals(last))
            result.add(cur);
        last = cur;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage example:

```
System.out.println(removeAdjacentDuplicates(
     Arrays.asList(1, 10, 10, 23, 31, 50, 50, 50, 65, 71, 89, 100)));
// [1, 10, 23, 31, 50, 65, 71, 89, 100]
```

Comment: Unfortunately duplicates may be an issue. What should I do if there are duplicates?

Comment: @YahyaUddin, you use `TreeSet` which silently removes duplicates. So your solution is not only slow, but incorrect?

Comment: No I WANTED to remove duplicates. But on seconds thoughts just assume I don't have duplicates